# Angular2 ng2-datetime-picker module binding

Tags: angular, npm

I was trying new things out with angular2 so I got got this problem now.
I wanted to bind https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime-picker in my module and there it says I have to bind it like

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2DatetimePickerModule],
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
 })
```

But the funny point is that I don't have @NgModule anywhere in my project. I just work with @Component.

My main.ts is looking like this, without @NgModule again:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

 import { AppComponent } from './src/index/app.component';
 import { SharedService } from './sharedService/SharedService';

 import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
 enableProdMode();

 bootstrap(AppComponent, [
     APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, SharedService
 ]);
```

and my AppComponent

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
import { FORM_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/forms';

import { TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS} from '../../translate/translation';
import { TranslateService } from '../../translate/translate.service';
import { TranslatePipe } from '../../translate/translate.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
        `<div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
            <app-login></app-login>
        </div>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [TranslatePipe],
    providers: [CookieService, FORM_PROVIDERS, TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS, TranslateService],
})

export class AppComponent {
    public constructor(private http: Http, private _translate: TranslateService) {
        /* Setting default lanaguage. */
        switch(navigator.language) {
            case 'de' : {
                _translate.use('de');
                break;
            }
            default: {
                _translate.use('en');
            }
        }
    }

    public requestAPI = function() {
        return this.http;
    }
}
```

So how can I use this library now? I don't know where to bind it. Would be very glad when anyone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your project is in rc* version of Angular. Try to port it to the latest 2.0.1. Here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html is more details about modules.

Comment: Oh so the problem was the version of my angular project? I've started completely new angular2 project and now it seems to work. Thanks for pointing me at this.